# Run npm install without node-gyp rebuild

Tags: node.js, npm

I do a node-gyp rebuild in my post install scripts. Running node-gyp rebuild during will error out. How can I run npm install without node-gyp rebuild?

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
npm install --ignore-scripts
```

But it's not perfect because it prevents to execute all scripts from all dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you don't want to install using `npm install --ignore-scripts` a for some reason use npm install only, you can override install script in package.json by some noop. For example:

```json
"scripts" : {
    "install" : "echo"
}
```

works like a charm (tested with yarn too)

Answer (score -3):

package.json under scripts do this:

```
"scripts": {
    "install": "install -d $(pwd)"
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Also I see no documented `-d` flag in npm's docs. Can you elaborate what's going on here?